# Tomae's Popcorn Function: Preimage of Opens?

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I'm just wondering what the preimage of an (open) neighborhood say $(-0.5,0.5)$ containing the point $T(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})=0$ under Tomae's popcorn function $T$ looks like.

Does somebody have an idea?

*(Of course this doesn't need to be open again so this might be an interesting example apart from other more obvious ones...)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The preimage is still open:
It cuts out a finite number of points for any open neighborhood of $T(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}})$